# How do I get a substring given a pattern?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

For SQL Server, let's say I have the following string:

> *FirstName changed from (Joe) to (Sally), LastName changed from (Doe) to (Harris)*

I would like to get both the new first name and last name.
SUBSTRING() would not be the proper way since there's no pattern on how many chars the new name has.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you could substring between the brackets?

Comment: The best way to solve this would be to use a more normalized design. You are storing multiple values in a single tuple which violates 1NF.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best if you [normalize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/database-normalization-description) your design.

#### Approach 1

However, with your current dataset following this pattern, a simple yet robust approach you may use, uses [`CHARINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in a recursive [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [`SUBSTRING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to extract the desired names. This will work for any number of pairs of open and closed brackets without considering the other contents of the string. In the final projection we can choose which pair we desire use the case expressions. I've included an example and explanations below:

```sql
WITH sample_data as (
   select 'FirstName changed from (Joe) to (Sally), LastName changed from (Doe) to (Harris)' as col
),
name_indexes AS (
     SELECT
         col, 
         CHARINDEX('(',col) as index_start ,
         CHARINDEX(')',col) as index_end,
         0 as iteration
     FROM
         sample_data
     UNION ALL
     SELECT
         col, 
         CHARINDEX('(',col,index_start + 1) as index_start ,
         CHARINDEX(')',col,index_end + 1) as index_end,
         iteration+1 as iteration
     FROM
         name_indexes
     WHERE
         iteration < 3
),
name_pieces AS (
    SELECT
         *,
         SUBSTRING(col,index_start+1,index_end - index_start-1) as name
    FROM
         name_indexes
),
name_changes AS (
    SELECT
        col,
        MAX(CASE WHEN iteration=0 THEN name END) as original_first_name,
        MAX(CASE WHEN iteration=1 THEN name END) as new_first_name,
        MAX(CASE WHEN iteration=2 THEN name END) as original_last_name,
        MAX(CASE WHEN iteration=3 THEN name END) as new_last_name
    FROM
        name_pieces
    GROUP BY 
        col
)
SELECT *
FROM name_changes
```

| col | original_first_name | new_first_name | original_last_name | new_last_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FirstName changed from (Joe) to (Sally), LastName changed from (Doe) to (Harris) | Joe | Sally | Doe | Harris |

*Working demo db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9a5092491ce147c91c2d70429f6b646d)*

The first CTE `sample_data` with column `col` is only for demonstration purposes as I try to replicate your table. You may omit this CTE and replace `sample_data` with your table name and `col` with your column storing the string to extract the changes in the query below:

```sql
WITH name_indexes AS (
     SELECT
         col, 
         CHARINDEX('(',col) as index_start ,
         CHARINDEX(')',col) as index_end,
         0 as iteration
     FROM
         sample_data
     UNION ALL
     SELECT
         col, 
         CHARINDEX('(',col,index_start + 1) as index_start ,
         CHARINDEX(')',col,index_end + 1) as index_end,
         iteration+1 as iteration
     FROM
         name_indexes
     WHERE
         iteration < 3
),
name_pieces AS (
    SELECT
         *,
         SUBSTRING(col,index_start+1,index_end - index_start-1) as name
    FROM
         name_indexes
),
name_changes AS (
    SELECT
        col,
        MAX(CASE WHEN iteration=0 THEN name END) as original_first_name,
        MAX(CASE WHEN iteration=1 THEN name END) as new_first_name,
        MAX(CASE WHEN iteration=2 THEN name END) as original_last_name,
        MAX(CASE WHEN iteration=3 THEN name END) as new_last_name
    FROM
        name_pieces
    GROUP BY 
        col
)
SELECT *
FROM name_changes
```

The CTE `name_indexes` is a recursive CTE aiming to extract the indexes of `(` and `)` to identify the start and end of each name change following the pattern in the string. `iteration` is used to track the number of changes and this recursive CTE continues while there are less than 3 iterations. The output looks like for this sample string:

| col | index_start | index_end | iteration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FirstName changed from (Joe) to (Sally), LastName changed from (Doe) to (Harris) | 24 | 28 | 0 |
| FirstName changed from (Joe) to (Sally), LastName changed from (Doe) to (Harris) | 33 | 39 | 1 |
| FirstName changed from (Joe) to (Sally), LastName changed from (Doe) to (Harris) | 64 | 68 | 2 |
| FirstName changed from (Joe) to (Sally), LastName changed from (Doe) to (Harris) | 73 | 80 | 3 |

The CTE `name_pieces` uses the `SUBSTRING` function to extract the names from the string based on the indexes. The output of this CTE is

| col | index_start | index_end | iteration | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FirstName changed from (Joe) to (Sally), LastName changed from (Doe) to (Harris) | 24 | 28 | 0 | Joe |
| FirstName changed from (Joe) to (Sally), LastName changed from (Doe) to (Harris) | 33 | 39 | 1 | Sally |
| FirstName changed from (Joe) to (Sally), LastName changed from (Doe) to (Harris) | 64 | 68 | 2 | Doe |
| FirstName changed from (Joe) to (Sally), LastName changed from (Doe) to (Harris) | 73 | 80 | 3 | Harris |

Finally, the CTE `name_changes` uses a group by and max function with case expressions to consolidate these changes into 1 row per string in the original dataset. You may choose your desired columns from this final projection.

| col | original_first_name | new_first_name | original_last_name | new_last_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FirstName changed from (Joe) to (Sally), LastName changed from (Doe) to (Harris) | Joe | Sally | Doe | Harris |

#### Approach 2

This approach is simply but assumes that your string will always be in the same format i.e. having a `to (` before the change and that the last name will be at the end. As a result it is more straight forward

```sql
with sample_data as (
   select 'FirstName changed from (Joe) to (Sally), LastName changed from (Doe) to (Harris)' as col
)
select 
    col,
    SUBSTRING(
        col,
        CHARINDEX('to (',col)+4,
        CHARINDEX('to (',col)+4-CHARINDEX(')',col) -1
    ) as new_first_name,
    SUBSTRING(
        col,
        CHARINDEX('to (',col,CHARINDEX('to (',col)+1)+4,
        LEN(col) - (CHARINDEX('to (',col,CHARINDEX('to (',col)+1)+4)
    ) as new_last_name
 from sample_data
```

***Outputs***

| col | new_first_name | new_last_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FirstName changed from (Joe) to (Sally), LastName changed from (Doe) to (Harris) | Sally | Harris |

[View working demo db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7dc438453f660d2e9c26d8345d65fb43)

---

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Others have already noted that if you are storing that as data in some column in some table then that's not a great schema. But maybe you just have a varchar variable you're trying to parse... your question doesn't actually specify that this data is in some column in some table.

Here is a somewhat "imperative" solution using cross apply. Cross apply is nice in situations like this, because it lets you compose the logic from smaller parts in a way that is easy to read. Is it the "best" way? That depends upon what you mean by best. I would argue it is very easy to understand and therefore maintain.

This solution will also work if your data *is* actually a column in a table, just replace the `values` constructor with the actual table.

```sql
declare @str varchar(1000) 
   = 'FirstName changed from (Joe) to (Sally), LastName changed from (Doe) to (Harris)';

select      originalString =  t.string,
            newFirstName   =  substring
                              (
                                 t.string, 
                                 newFirstStart.pos, 
                                 newFirstEnd.pos - newFirstStart.pos
                              ),
            newLastName    =  substring
                              (
                                 t.string, 
                                 newLastStart.pos, 
                                 len(t.string) - newLastStart.pos
                              )
from        (values (@str)) t(string)
cross apply (select charindex('to (', string, 0) + 4)                newFirstStart(pos)
cross apply (select charindex(')', string, newFirstStart.pos))       newFirstEnd(pos)
cross apply (select charindex('to (', string, newFirstEnd.pos) + 4)  newLastStart(pos);
```

The question is really how robust you need your solution to be. This answer assumes that your input string always has the parentheses around the names, and that the names don't *themselves* contain parentheses, and the rest of the string is invariant. If that's not exactly true, similar solutions may exist using more convoluted `charindex` constructions, or  `patindex`, or even splitting the string into words (using one of the many available TSQL string split implementations, or the built in `string_split` in SQL Server 2016+).

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to achieve by using tokenization via XML/XQuery.

The tokenization process is producing the following XML behind the scenes:

```
<root>
  <r>FirstName changed from </r>
  <r>Joe</r>
  <r> to </r>
  <r>Sally</r>
  <r>, LastName changed from </r>
  <r>Doe</r>
  <r> to </r>
  <r>Harris</r>
  <r />
</root>
```

After that we just need to get 2nd, 4th, 6th, and 8th tokens.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @tokens VARCHAR(MAX) 
   = 'FirstName changed from (Joe) to (Sally), LastName changed from (Doe) to (Harris)';

DECLARE @close CHAR(1) = ')'
    , @open CHAR(1) = '(';

SELECT original_first_name = c.value('(/root/r[2]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)')
    , new_first_name = c.value('(/root/r[4]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)')
    , original_last_name = c.value('(/root/r[6]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)')
    , new_last_name = c.value('(/root/r[8]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)')
FROM (values (@tokens)) t(col)
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
            REPLACE(REPLACE(col, @open, @close), @close, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
            ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c);
```

**Output**

```
+---------------------+----------------+--------------------+---------------+
| original_first_name | new_first_name | original_last_name | new_last_name |
+---------------------+----------------+--------------------+---------------+
| Joe                 | Sally          | Doe                | Harris        |
+---------------------+----------------+--------------------+---------------+
```